# Is $S\cup\{v\}$ is linearly dependent or linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Is the following statement is **true/false** ?

Let $S$ be a linearly independent subset of a vector space $V.$
Suppose $v$ is a vector in $V$ which is not in the subspace spanned by $S$. Then
the set obtained by adjoining $v$ to **$S$ is linearly dependent**

**My attempt** : **no**

It given that $S$ is linearly independent . we will denote set obtained by adjoining $v$ to $S$  by  $S\cup\{v\}$ so  there is a  distinct vectors $u_1,u_2,...,u_n\in S\cup\{v\}$ and a collection of non-zero scalars $c_1,c_2,...,c_n$ such that $$c_1u_1+c_2u_2+\cdots+c_nu_n=0.\tag{1}$$ Since the $c_i$s are non-zero and $S$ is linearly independent, then we can't have all the $u_i$s in $S,$ so one of them is $v$. Without loss of generality , say $u_1=v$, and so the rest are in $S$. Since $c_1\neq 0,$ we can solve $(1)$ to get $$v=u_1=-\frac1{c_1}\left(c_2u_2+\cdots+c_nu_n\right)\in\text{span}\{u_2,...,u_n\}\subseteq\text{span }S.$$

This implies that $S\cup\{v\}$ is **linearly independent**

Edit : Proof verification

Comment: you basically have a proof by contradiction showing linear independence. Note that $v$ is not in $S$ by assumption.

Comment: What is your question? Do you want us to check your solution? Then you better add the `solution-verification` tag

Comment: It's not valid to conclude that some $u_k = v$. Do your definitions assume finite-dimensional vector spaces, or could you need to handle the case of infinite-dimensional $V$ and/or $S$ as well?

Comment: yes @aschepler its  about finite dimensional vector space

Comment: ya  i edit its @VIVID

Comment: Never mind the first part - I see why the way you set it up, $u_k = v$ for some $k$.

Comment: @aschepler basically  $u_1,u_2,...,u_n\in S\cup\{v\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'd consider a set of vectors $u_1,\ldots,u_n$ in $S$ and the vector $v$.

Suppose $c_0 v + c_1u_1+\ldots+c_nu_n=0$ with $c_0\ne 0$; the case $c_0$ is uninteresting.

Then $v = -\frac{1}{c_0}(c_1u_1+\ldots+c_nu_n)$ lies in the subspace spanned by $S$, a contradiction.

Thus $c_0=0$ and since $u_1,\ldots,u_n\in S$ are linearly independent, it follows that all $c_i$'s are $0$. Hence, $S\cup\{v\}$ is a linearly independent set.

Comment: thanks u @Wuestenfux i forgot about $c_0=0$ when i was solving this  question.now got it!!